# How to exclude some junit tests from failsafe reports but not from execution?

Tags: maven, jbehave, maven-failsafe-plugin, thucydides

I am using Jenkins + Maven + Java for continuous testing, and recently Thucydides + JBehave were added. I am pretty new to Jenkins and Thucydides, so I faced trouble with showing the build reports.

I don't have rights to change Jenkins configuration, so I cannot add some plugin for correct showing the Thucydides reports. I can attach Thucydides report to the build using existing Jenkins plugin, but I also need some standard JUnit reports (for correct email notification, etc.).

And JUnit "thinks" that there are 28 tests, when actually there is 6 scenarios. Failsafe plugin generates report xml file where:

```
<testcase time="0.027" classname="java.lang.Object" name="BeforeStories"/>
<testcase time="0.032" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Given 2"/>
<testcase time="0.002" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="When adding 3"/>
<testcase time="0.003" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Then equals to 5"/>
<testcase time="0.011" classname="Scenario: 2 + 3 = 5" name="Scenario: 2 + 3 = 5"/>
<testcase time="0.002" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Given 3"/>
<testcase time="0.002" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="When adding 3\u200B"/>
<testcase time="0.002" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Then equals to 6"/>
<testcase time="0.009" classname="Scenario: 3 + 3 = 6" name="Scenario: 3 + 3 = 6"/>
<testcase time="0.002" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Given 3\u200B"/>
<testcase time="0.003" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="When adding 4"/>
<testcase time="0.002" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Then equals to 7"/>
<testcase time="0.01" classname="Scenario: 3 + 4 = 7" name="Scenario: 3 + 4 = 7"/>
<testcase time="0.014" classname="Additional.story" name="Additional.story"/>
<testcase time="0.003" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Given 2\u200B"/>
<testcase time="0.001" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="When adding 2"/>
<testcase time="0.003" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Then equals to 4"/>
<testcase time="0.01" classname="Scenario: 2 + 2 = 4" name="Scenario: 2 + 2 = 4"/>
<testcase time="0.002" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Given 3\u200B\u200B"/>
<testcase time="0.001" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="When adding 5"/>
<testcase time="0.002" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Then equals to 8"/>
<testcase time="0.009" classname="Scenario: 3 + 5 = 8" name="Scenario: 3 + 5 = 8"/>
<testcase time="0.004" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Given 3\u200B\u200B\u200B"/>
<testcase time="0.005" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="When adding 6"/>
<testcase time="0.001" classname="TestPhucydidesJBehave.jbehave.DefinitionSteps" name="Then equals to 9"/>
<testcase time="0.008" classname="Scenario: 3 + 6 = 9" name="Scenario: 3 + 6 = 9"/>
<testcase time="0.012" classname="Simple.story" name="Simple.story"/>
<testcase time="0.006" classname="java.lang.Object" name="AfterStories"/>
```

As you could see there is a lot of excess stuff there. I don't know how to "explain" to Failsafe and JUnit, that "tests" - are only scenarios.

Any tips would be very helpful!

Comment: Have you taken a look into the documentaiton about using the jbehave-maven-plugin ? http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/maven-goals.html

Comment: We don't use "clean" JBehave, we use Thucydides to run JBehave stories: thucydides-jbehave-plugin, thucydides-junit and thucydides-core.